# Getting current MP3 filename with AVAudioPlayer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I've got AVAudioPlayer playing some MP3 in background. AVAudioPlayer is singleton instance shared across app. Is it possible to detect current filename of MP3 being played at a time? I can't see any method in delegate, there's *duration*, *currentTime* but nor *filename* or something like this.

Other thing I consider if this method fails is reading MP3 tags and get track name from it - is it possible with AVAudioPlayer?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get **filename of current playing media in AVAudioPlayer** like this:

```
NSString *mediaFileName = [[youAVAudioPlayer.url absoluteString] lastPathComponent];
```

Note condition is that: **Returns nil if the audio player was not initialized with a URL**.

Answer (score 2):

If you initialize the AVAudioPlayer with a `url`, you can read that property. AVAudioPlayer does not read the tags in the MP3 file, so it will not help with that.

You may find [AVAsset](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAsset_Class/Reference/Reference.html) interesting as a way to get metadata from an MP3. [Quick Tutorial](http://www.arlt.eu/blog/tag/id3/).